# express router is not working in nodejs typescript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express, express-router

I have created registerClass where i will add all the routes for this application , this node app is using typescript so all the source is in `dist` directory. what i am missing in below code when i call `http://localhost:9001/user` endpoint it is not going into registerRouteClass ? i guess it is not reading the dist dir

server.js

```
const express = require("express"),
    path = require("path"),
    app = express();
var router = require('./dist');

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist')));
app.use(new router.TRouter().getRouter);

app.listen(9001, () => console.log('Example app listening on port 9001!'));
```

routes.ts

```
import {UserController} from './api/user/user.controller';
export class RegisterRouteClass {
    public RegisterRoutes(app: any) {
      console.log("registing routes");
        app.post('/user', UserController.findAll);
    }

}
```

index.ts

```
import {NextFunction, Request, Response, Router} from 'express';
import * as bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import {RegisterRouteClass} from "./routes";

// this variable will be exported to be included as a middleware.
class TRouter extends RegisterRouteClass {
    private TRouter: any;

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.TRouter = Router();
        this.TRouter.use(bodyParser.json());
        this.TRouter.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
        this.TRouter.use(function(_req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
            // CORS header
            res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
            res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
            res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization');
            res.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
            next();
        });

    }

    public get getRouter() {
        return this.TRouter;
    }


}


export {TRouter};
```

directory structure

```
Project
 - dist 
  -index.js
  -routes.js
  -api
   - user
     -user.constrollr.js
-server.js
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all your project structure looks little bit odd but, in your `server.js`, by `var router = require('./dist')` you are not actually requiring anything since in your `index.js` you don't have a default export only name export.

You should either have a default export in your `index.ts` or do `var router = require('./dist').TRouter`. I'd go with default export.